# Converting BufferedImage or ImageIO to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I read a image through BufferedImage get its RGB value, Now for writing the image back, instead of using the ImageIO, I have to write the Image in HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System). Now I have only one option to use that is using 
      FSDataOutputStream to write. 
So Is it possible to convert the RGB values from the buffered image to ByteBuffer class in Java?? Pls.Help

Answer (score 5):

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\image\\mypic.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageInByte);
```

Source: http://jaypthakkar.blogspot.de/2014/01/convert-bufferedimage-to-bytebuffer.html

Comment: whats the use of baos.flush();

Comment: It works. And flush, read the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29

Comment: but should u think the flush method should be placed above the write method.?

Comment: I run it, and i see it make no differend. but I am not sure if there are casses there you need it